# Should nodes of trees and similar data structures be visible to the outside?

Tags: api, data-structures, tree

I've read "Michael T. Goodrich's Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" book and often stumbled about method signatures like the following example taken from the tree section:

`public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v)`

To me the proposed API looks a bit weird. I don't understand why they make the `Position` class/objects available to the outside world. Personally I would have created something like this:

`public E parent(E e)`

I see that, given that the `Position` stores a reference to it's parent, the second variant is slower because the method first has to locate `e`'s `Position` object within the tree. Whereas the first method could return the reference in constant time.

But the version from the book would allow the member function `parent()` to run even with position objects not stored in the associated tree, which in my opinion is very strange.

Are there any good reasons for the first version I'm not taking into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it strange to call `parent()` on objects that are not in the tree? You can do that with the second version too, i.e. you could call `parent(E)` on some `E` that's not in the tree.

Generally, I think exposing the tree structure makes sense when what you are providing to the users is a tree. If you were for example creating an associative array, using a tree, you shouldn't even expose the `parent()` method.

Other reason for the first one might be that some `E` might not be unique in the tree. So if some `E` is in the tree twice, each time with different parent, it's unclear what should `parent(E)` return. `parent(Position<E>)` doesn't have this problem.

And the performance reason can be significant too. If it's the difference between `O(N)` and `O(1)`, then it's certainly worth it.

Comment: hi svick. thank you for your answer. your point of view seems very reasonable to me. I think its strange, because if we had two Tree's `A` and `B` each containing Positions `a` and `b` respectively a call to `B.parent(a)` would return `a`'s parent in `A`. But I understand that this side effect is unimportant compared to the performance issue.

Comment: @aka, in that case, it makes more sense to have the `parent()` method directly on `Position<E>`, rather than on the tree.